# Identify story: the farther an object travels, the more power it gains

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to identify a snippet of memory I have from some story, book, video game, movie or television show.

All I can remember is that an object (not sure if it's a specific artifact of if this applies to any object) gains power, magic, or importance by traveling. Basically, the farther it travels, the more powerful it becomes.

In the story, the most powerful object is a satellite (or piece of a satellite, or object placed aboard a satellite) since it has orbited the Earth many times. I think people are fighting over it, or trying to find it.

Does anyone know what my memory corresponds to?

Thank you.

Comment: Samuel W. Taylor's short story "A Situation of Gravity" (1943) fits your material properties. It's near impossible to find. Storyline doesn't fit. Disney did the plot as "The Absent Minded Professor" (1961) AKA **Flubber**.

Answer (score 19):

This is is "[The Barsoom Project](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/218470.The_Barsoom_Project)" which is the sequel to Dream Park (mentioned in @JamesMcleod's [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/81426/20774)). In the book, talismans gain power by traveling, and the powerful object in question is a piece of a satellite.

One of the characters lives on a space station, and her gear has a great deal of magical energy.

Comment: Dang. You're right, I think. I had forgotten I'd even read that. +1.